# Android RoboSpice and cookies in requests

Tags: android, cookies, oauth, robospice

I have next problem:

I auth via oauth and webview, after that i store cookies in sharedPreferences and setting it in ClientHttpRequestInterceptor.
Via logs new cookies are setting for new requests, but on server i get old cookies until i fully restart application.

Here is my JsonSpiceService:
http://pastebin.com/Wiaf6NkJ

Here is my activity where i set cookies:
http://pastebin.com/f5F0JCnd

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After trying to fix this, i noticed that RoboSpice and Spring ignore setting of cookies after receiving set-cookie header. So, i send request that receives correct set-cookie header and fixed this issue.